# Enable Frames for All 2D Plots in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

To set all the 2D plots to have the option `Frame->True`, i added the following to my "init.m":

```
(SetOptions[#, Frame -> True]&)/@{Plot,ListPlot,ListLinePlot,LogPlot,LogLogPlot,LogLinearPlot};
```

Which seems awkward and i never have all the different plots in the list.

Is there a simpler/better way for me to set these options *en masse*?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finds every builtin that has `Plot` in its name and a `Frame` option:

```
 Select[Symbol /@ Names["System`*Plot*"] , 
         MemberQ[Options[#]   , Frame -> _] & ]
```

```
{ArrayPlot, BodePlot, CommunityGraphPlot, ContourPlot, \
DateListLogPlot, DateListPlot, DensityPlot, DiscretePlot, GraphPlot, \
LayeredGraphPlot, LineIntegralConvolutionPlot, ListContourPlot, \
ListCurvePathPlot, ListDensityPlot, ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot, \
ListLinePlot, ListLogLinearPlot, ListLogLogPlot, ListLogPlot, \
ListPlot, ListPolarPlot, ListStreamDensityPlot, ListStreamPlot, \
ListVectorDensityPlot, ListVectorPlot, LogLinearPlot, LogLogPlot, \
LogPlot, MatrixPlot, NicholsPlot, NyquistPlot, ParametricPlot, Plot, \
PolarPlot, ProbabilityPlot, ProbabilityScalePlot, QuantilePlot, \
RegionPlot, ReliefPlot, RootLocusPlot, SingularValuePlot, \
StreamDensityPlot, StreamPlot, TreePlot, VectorDensityPlot, \
VectorPlot, WaveletListPlot, WaveletMatrixPlot}
```

so you can use your approach simply:

```
 SetOptions[#, Frame -> True]&/@Select[Symbol /@ Names["System`*Plot*"],
   MemberQ[Options[#]   , Frame -> _] & ];
```

If you want to expand to things that don't have `Plot` in their name you need to use `Quiet` because a handful of symbols throw warnings when you request options:

```
      Select[Symbol /@ Names["System`*"] , 
             MemberQ[Quiet@Options[#]   , Frame -> _] & ]
```

Fair warning I have no idea of the consequences of changing the default on all that stuff..

Comment: Thank you! That answer teaches me something about the system as well! Thanks!